# Installing wall mount light fixture - what to do with ground wire

Tags: electrical

I am installing a wall mounted light fixture.  The fixture can either be plugged into a wall outlet or hardwired into an outlet. I am choosing to plug the fixture into a wall outlet.  In addition to the cord/plug, there is a ground wire on the fixture.

[image]

I get what to do with the ground wire if the fixture was going to be hardwired, but this is not what I'm planning to do.   So what do I do with the ground wire.  The installation instructions only address the ground wire in the context of hardwiring.  Can I leave the ground wire as it is, can I cut it off?

Comment: Can we see a picture of the wiring?

Comment: I added a picture to my original post.

Comment: In theory, if the device is UL approved, and the plug does not have a ground, you don't need one for a plug-in mounting. But is there a way to route that cord so the edge of the fixture does not cut it?

Answer (score 2):

I would simply coil it up neatly and not cut it off.   Who knows, you might decide to install it "wired" sometime down the road.

Your plug being 2-prong (no ground), I would still be tempted to ground it.

Comment: I will coil it up as you suggest.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to anything with the ground since you are plugging it in. If it was required for the plug then they should have given you a plug with a ground prong. You could cut off the ground wire, or tape it inside the fixture in case you ever decide to hardware it.

Comment: I like the option of just coiling it up and taping it inside the fixture.  thank you.